# Swift does not generates forward declaration for protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have a swift class defined in a framework that is being used from an obj-c app.

The generated -Swift.h header contains the swift classes marked with @objc but there's one property that makes the compilation fail.

This property is defined like this in swift code :

```
public var storageClass : StorageProtocol.Type = UserDefaultStorage.self
```

and so the generated obj-c property looks like this

```
@property (nonatomic) Class <StorageProtocol> __nonnull storageClass;
```

But Xcode does not accepts the "StorageProtocol" symbol here, because the forward declaration "@protocol StorageProtocol;" is missing.

If I add a new var defined like this :

```
public var storage : StorageProtocol? = nil
```

The forward declaration is added on top of class that define these properties and the -Swift.h compilation succeed.

So it looks like a bug in the -Swift.h generation, but is there another way to force that forward declaration without using a dummy var ?

Comment: Have you tested this with the latest Xcode 7.2? I've been trying a number of different configurations to get this to happen, and haven't been able to reproduce so far. Are you able to reproduce in a small project?

Comment: I'm downloading xcode 7.2 so i'll be able to test.

Comment: Still getting the error even with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any other way than using a dummy var...